# Web3 | TransferFrom() transactions always Failed

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm trying to send Custom ERC20 Token to Owner Wallet Address using transferFrom() function using Web3.js

However all the Transactions are failed. Which is the same problem occur on Remix IDE. 
Some answers on stackOverflow here says that the `approve()` is needed to call first before the `transferFrom()` function. so, I tried on Remix frist but I got the same problem. And then tried with using Web3.js like below.

```
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
const amount = sendAmount;
let address = myAddress;
myContract.options.address = contractAddress;
myContract.options.from = TokenOwner;
let options = myContract.options;
let data1 = myContract.methods.approve(address, amount).encodeABI();
let data2 = myContract.methods.transferFrom(address, TokenOwner, amount).encodeABI();

const ethAccount = fromPrivateKey(toBuffer("0x..."));
const fromPrivateKeyBuffer = ethAccount.getPrivateKey();

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(TokenOwner, (err, count) => {
  if (err) return;

  const txData = {
    chainId: 0x03,
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(42000000000),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(90000),
    to: contractAddress,
    from: TokenOwner,
    value: 0x0,
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count),
    data: data1
  };
  const tx = new ethTx(txData);
  tx.sign(fromPrivateKeyBuffer);
  const serializedTx = tx.serialize().toString("hex");
  if (!serializedTx) {
    return;
  } else {
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedTx}`, (err, MuiTXHash) => {
      console.log("err : ", err, "Data1-MuiTXHash : ", MuiTXHash);
      // START DATA2
      web3.eth.getTransactionCount(TokenOwner, (err, count) => {
        if (err) return;

        const txData2 = {
          chainId: 0x03,
          gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(42000000000),
          gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(90000),
          to: contarctAddress,
          from: TokenOwner,
          value: 0x0,
          nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count + 1),
          data: data2
        };
        const tx2 = new ethTx(txData2);
        tx2.sign(fromPrivateKeyBuffer);
        const serializedTx2 = tx2.serialize().toString("hex");
        if (!serializedTx2) {
          return;
        } else {
          web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedTx2}`, (err, MuiTXHash2) => {
            console.log("err : ", err, "Data2-MuiTXHash : ", MuiTXHash2);
          });
        }
      });
      // END DATA2
    });
  }
});
```

};

I got the two Transaction Hash return data and the TransferFrom() transaction is failed again.
What is the problem?
How can I make it success? I have to withdraw the custom ERC20 token from specific address to owner. so I have to use transferFrom() transaction. 
Please let me know how to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- txData: **TokenOwner** approve **myAddress** spend **amount** token

=> txData2: **myAddress** now can transfer from **TokenOwner** address **amount** token to any address

```
let data2 = myContract.methods.transferFrom(TokenOwner, toAddress, amount).encodeABI();
```

and

```
txData2 = {
      chainId: 0x03,
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(42000000000),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(90000),
      to: contarctAddress,
      from: address,
      value: 0x0,
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count + 1),
      data: data2
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta do this in this order if you want to send token into a contract

```
mytoken.methods.approve(contractAddress, amount).send({from: accounts[0]}).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
      myContract.methods.transferFrom(tokenOwnerAddress, contractAddress, amount).
        send({from: accounts[0]}).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
            // do something with receipt object
        })
```

I think you are calling approve function from outside the token contract. you gotta call it directly from the token contract and then call your transferFrom function from some other contract.